# railsでcssを使うにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

views内にあるindex.html.erbを編集し、mycss.cssを反映させようとしていますがうまくいきません。以下の二つのパターンでコードをhtml内に書き試しましたがうまくいきませんでした。
初歩的で申し訳ありませんが宜しくお願いします。

1.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "mycss", media: "all","data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

2.

```
<link href="css/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: どのようなエラーが表示されるのか記述してください。stackoverflowの質問にコードを記述するときはCtrl-kすると良いです。一般的にスタイルシートの読み込みは/app/views/layouts/application.html.erbで行ったほうがよろしいかと思われます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

落ち着いて。Railsだから反映されないという事は、滅多にありません。
なぜならブラウザが取得しているのは、普通のHTMLコンテンツに過ぎないからです。

まず「ファイルが読み込めていない」のか「反映されていない」のか切り分けましょう。
直接URL叩いてもいいのですがF12(開発者ツールと呼ばれるもの)を開いてください。
例えばChromeならばNetworksタブからmycss.cssの読み込みに、エラーが生じて赤字となっていないか確認してください。

もしエラーが生じている場合。アクセスしようとしたパスを確認して、自分の想定と正しいかどうか確認してください。直接そのURLへアクセスしてみて、もしrailsのroutes-errorだった場合は、おそらくファイルの配置が正しくありません。この場合は、アクセスしようとしたURL。ソース表示から見えるlinkタグ。実際に配置したファイルのパス。この3つの情報が必要になります。

もし正しくファイルが読み込めている場合は、おそらくCSS記述の問題です。
railsとは関係なく「このCSS定義が反映されない」みたいな話になりますので再度整理してください。試しに mycss.css には`body { background-color: #FFA; }`だけのようなミニマム記述して、反映されるか確認しましょう。

これは、現時点での想定ですが。直接linkタグいれたパターンが
`css/mycss.css`となっていますが。`/css/mycss.css`の間違いではありませんか？
これですと`http://example.com/admin/user/1`みたいなURLから参照した場合
`http://example.com/admin/user/css/mycss.css`へのアクセスとなりますので
(public配置の場合)`/public/admin/user/css/mycss.css`にファイルを設置しなくてはなりません。

もし貴方が`/public/css/mycss.css`へファイルを設置している場合。記述するべきは`stylesheet_link_tag "/css/mycss"` か `href="/css/mycss.css"`のはずです。

### 追記

stylesheet_link_tag の パス生成ロジックは、
stylesheet_path ( http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper/stylesheet_path )に委任しています。 exampleに記述された生成結果の例も確認してください。

Comment: パスが間違っていたようで、読み込めるようにました。
ご丁寧に回答いただき感謝しております。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

プロジェクトの `app/assets/stylesheets/` 配下に `mycss.css`を置きましょう。自動的に読み込まれます。

`stylesheet_link_tag`での指定もこの場合は必要ありません。

Comment: 補足として。標準的な環境の場合は、assets配下にして「自動的に取り込まれた」後、その取り込まれたcssを呼び出すために`stylesheet_link_tag 'application'`が必要になります。./app/views/layouts/application.html.erbに記述がありますのでその行を大事にしてください。

Comment: 回答いただきありがとうございました。参考にさせていただきうまくいくようになりました。大変感謝しております。